# Android custom notification background

Tags: android, notifications, custom-notification

I have a custom notification with RelativeLayout in root of my layout. I need to set background image to this RelativeLayout. I have an image url and then I download Bitmap using Picasso. 
Is there a way to set Bitmap to custom notification?

All answers are about settings color or image which are located in resources `remoteView.setInt(R.id.viewid, "setBackgroundResource", R.color.your_color)`.

Comment: did you use this method?    setImageViewBitmap(int viewId, Bitmap bitmap)

Comment: the problem is that viewId is not an imageView, but a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't add background to RelativeLayout, but I found a workaround. I made layout like this

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

ImageView now works as background because it goes first in FrameLayout.